# User name who flagged in Global Node flag

Tags: views, flags

I have a global node flag where editors can flag the Node article as famous. There are more than 10 editors, so, I want to display in the node who flagged it and when. I used Views Relationships to get the flag data, I could easily get the flagged time but couldn't get flagged user. I tried with flag users relationship but it results in Anonymous user instead of the user who flagged.

Is there any way I can display the user who flagged it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are in similar situation, I'd like to inform that at the time of writing, **This is Not Possible with Flag**. [Flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) module is just ***Boolean*** true/false.

I changed the ***flag*** to ***Vote*** using [VotingAPI](https://drupal.org/project/votingapi) and [Plus One](https://drupal.org/project/plus1) modules. The [VotingAPI](https://drupal.org/project/votingapi) has [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) integration and via views ***Relationship***, I could get the ***User information*** and ***Vote Timestamp*** to display in the page.